# Removing dups from unsorted LinkedList algorithm not making sense

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm having hard time understanding the following algorithm. The goal here is to remove duplicates from an unsorted LinkedList:

We have a Node class:

```
public class Node {
int data;
Node next;

Node(int data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

This is the method to remove dups from the linkedList:

```
private static void removeDuplicates(Node head) {

    if (head == null) {
        return;
    }

    Node current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        Node runner = current;
        while (runner.next != null) {
            if (runner.next.data == current.data) {
                runner.next = runner.next.next; // (1) <-- here
            } else {
                runner = runner.next;
            }
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
}
```

// Test case
    Node node1 = new Node(2);
    Node node2 = new Node(2); <-- ignored node
    Node node3 = new Node(3);
    Node node4 = new Node(4);
    Node node5 = new Node(8);
    Node node6 = new Node(16);
    Node node7 = new Node(32);
    Node node8 = new Node(8);

node1.next = node2;
        node2.next = node3;
        node3.next = node4;
        node4.next = node5;
        node5.next = node6;
        node6.next = node7;
        node7.next = node8;
        node8.next = null;

After executing (1) in the first iteration:
runner.data = 2
runner.next.data = 3
current.data = 2
current.next.data = 3 ??? **WHY?**

**PROBLEM:**
It makes sense that **node** 'runner.next.data' is **3**, because now the **2nd node** of value **2** is ignored.
But how come **node** 'current' also is ignoring the 2nd node? We never wrote to **node** 'current'. We only interacted with 'runner' **node**.

Comment: Because both `runner` and `current` refer to the same object - if you change this object via `runner` reference, this change will be seen in the `current`.  Moreover, atfer the first iteration this change is also applied to `head` :)

Comment: @AlexRudenko can you please explain how is this different from: 
private static void test() {
        int x = 4;
        int y = x;

        y = 6;
        System.out.println("Result is: x=" + x + " y=" + y);
    }
// Result is: x=4 y=6

Comment: `int` is primitive type, it is not an object, so when you assign a number `x` to a number `y`, there are actually two different numbers and value of `x` = 4 is copied to the number `y`.  More interesting is that if you used Integer object wrapper in your example, the result would be the same as for primitive `int`s. :)